# How to make sure a string postal code follows the 6 character letter digit, letter digit, letter digit, pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, postal-code

My current code is:

```
System.out.println(DATA_DIV);
System.out.println("Enter the Postal Code:");
postalCode = uIn.next();
postalCode = postalCode.toUpperCase();
```

what is the easiest and quickest way to check that every odd character is a letter and that every even character is a digit
Example
M3H4P3

Comment: Well, the "simple" solution would probably use a regular expression of some kind.  Really basically, something like `^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]`, but I'm sure there's some nice neat with to do repeating patterns

Comment: Or `^(?:[a-zA-Z][0-9]){3}` for the pattern repeated 3 times (after the initial match).  But, I suspect that that's not what your instructor is going to be looking for, so you're going to need to setup a loop and one or more flags and test each character